# Reusable Component Library with Angular

Tags: angular

I am building a reusable component library.  I am also creating multiple stand alone angular apps that are also libraries. The idea is to create a main application that imports the other applications' components and serves up those apps from an 'app library'. This way each app is stand alone and also included in a bundle.

I can import my reusable component library in a standalone app or in the app library, but I cannot do both. For instance I have a layout component that will be used by every app including the library. When I import the layout's module into both a standalone app and the library, the imports conflict (because I am also importing the standalone app into the library). I'm getting an error that says that the module has already been imported and cannot be defined twice.

FYI: My layout component has a number of router outlets for header, left nav, etc. I am injecting the components through the routes / child routes. If I setup a generic component in a route in the routing module, the generic module needs to be imported into app module which leads to conflicting router definitions.

Is it possible to use my reusable component library in the standalone apps and the library? How can I circumvent the conflicting modules?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "standalone angular apps that are also libraries" or maybe give examples? Trying to understand how can an app be standalone, and at the same time be a library.

Comment: I wanted to have an angular app where I could export components to be used in a library app

Comment: So I would like to build an angular app that runs as a normal Angular app with components, routes, and modules. When you navigate to a url in a browser the route loads from the application. I would also like the components in that application to be imported into another.  Essentially I am building a reusable component library, a standalone angular app, and an app library that consumes the standalone app (along with others). So the app library will pull in the main module from the standalone app along with routes and provide that application as its own.